# Not defined Substr in PHP

Tags: php, string, web, substr

I tried substr() method in PHP 5.6 to get some part of String,

*first,*

```
<?php
    echo substr("Avicienna", 0,3);
```

and save it to a file.

*second one,*

```
<?php
    class Test{
        public function index(){
            $name = "Hasan";
            var_dump(subtr($name,0,3));
        }
    }

$test = new Test();
$test->index();
```

and save it to another file.

the first one without class, return correct string parts, while, the second one return PHP 500 error :

```
Call to undefined method Coba::subtr() in /var/www/html/koper/coba.php on line 5
```

is there any limitation to call substr() or others php function inside a class ?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo error `subtr()` . Its `substr()`.